# How to get JBoss 7.1.3 to use my $JAVA_HOME environment varaible?

Tags: jboss, environment-variables, jboss7.x, java-home

I'm using Mac 10.9.5 with JBoss 7.1.3.Final.  I am launching JBoss through the termianl (bash shell), like so

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro:core davea$ cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin
Daves-MacBook-Pro:bin davea$ sudo sh standalone.sh
```

Within the shell, I can see that $JAVA_HOME is defined ...

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro:bin davea$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

However, JBoss is not picking up this environment variable (it is using a Java 8 installation that I also have on my machine), forcing me to uncomment the following line in my $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf file ...

```
JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Although this is straightforward, I would prefer a solution that is more automatic.  Does anyone know what I have to do to get JBoss to recognize the $JAVA_HOME environment variable I have set in my shell without my having to hard-code the value in a Jboss config?

**Edit:**

(In response to the commnent posted) Keep in mind I’m doing all this from the same shell.  So here is where I have shown I have the $JAVA_HOME environment var defined …

```
Daves-MacBook-Pro:bin davea$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then I edit my $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/bin/standalone.conf file in the way you suggest …

```
echo JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
echo "DONe with echo"
#JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

and when I re-run the startup script, this is what prints out …

```
JAVA_HOME=
DONe with echo
```

Comment: If you run the jboss, what happened, it the terminal stopped? or there is an exception?, please explain more.

Comment: Just to test try adding `echo JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME` in the `standalone.conf` before you set it. Maybe it's just not set in your session. Side note you can use `JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6)` so you don't have to hard-code your path.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question to show the output in response to your "echo JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME" suggestion.  Regarding the side note, I'm trying to create a situation where I can easily switch between Java 6 and Java 7 so I'd really like to use the $JAVA_HOME as a central place to control that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you really want to use `sudo`, you have to add the `-E` parameter to preserve the environment variables.